# Can't call a lazy lambda function with parameters via boost::phoenix::function

Tags: c++, lambda, parameter-passing, lazy-evaluation, boost-spirit

I tried to call  `boost::phoenix::function` based on lambda function with parameters and failed. If I call it without parameters in such a way:

```
const auto closure = [](){
    cout<< "test" << endl;
};

typedef decltype(closure) ClosureType;
const boost::phoenix::function<ClosureType> lazyFunc (std::move(closure));
lazyFunc()();
```

all compiles nice. But when I declare at least one parameter of lambda:

```
const auto  closure = [](int& param)  { cout<<"Test" << param << endl; };

typedef decltype(closure) ClosureType;
const boost::phoenix::function<ClosureType> lazyFunc (std::move(closure));
lazyFunc(arg1)(a);
```

compilation fails with tremendous stack trace deep inside of [boost::result_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/utility/result_of.hpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the error points to somewhere deep inside Boost.ResultOf (as seen in [this demo](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1243deeb57fcb250e30fa80a12382d7f)), that would be because the closure type of a lambda expression does not implement the ResultOf protocol.

A somewhat simple workaround to that is to define `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE`, which makes `boost::result_of` bypass its own ResultOf protocol by instead using `decltype` to compute return types. This is not enabled by default because not many compilers (at the time of the release of Boost 1.51) are conformant enough for this feature to work; it is planned that this symbol be defined automatically (by Boost.Config) for those compilers that can deal with it for 1.52.

[Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f2fa417f46f778a7ff9ef8226a6d6d53) is a demo of what it looks like to use Boost.Phoenix with a `decltype`-powered `boost::result_of`. I had to change the `int&` to `int const&` because `i` is apparently being forwarded as a `const int`. This appears to be a fundamental limitation of `boost::phoenix::function`, using `boost::phoenix::val` doesn't have this problem.